# Can I run Apache on other address other than localhost (127.0.0.1)

Tags: apache-http-server, proxy, localhost, proxy-server

I have a proxy server on my system that current runs on `127.0.0.1` which I use to browse the internet, hence I cannot access my apache localhost for local development.

I would like to know if there is a way to **access apache on another address** or **run my proxy server on another address**.

Answer (score 3):

You'll can change which port it's listening on, either the proxy server or Apache, whichever is most convenient.

Information on how to do this for apache is [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html) - effectively, have a line stating

`Listen XXX`

where XXX is the port number you wish to use in your apache conf. Then, visit

`http://127.0.0.1:XXX`

in your web browser.